# Is there a way to stop reference equality checking in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, operator-overloading, equality

Since there's [no way to do operator overloading in TypeScript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2319), is there a way I can tell the transpiler/IDE that this isn't allowed:

`this.vector1 == this.vector2;`

I have vectors which I want to be treated like value types, but since I can't overload `operator==`, is there a way to stop others (any myself!) from doing reference equality on them?

I was thinking of perhaps a way to decorate the type with something that says '*I'm a value type*', and have a TSLint rule or something that says '*No calling reference equals on value types*'

Comment: If your vectors are immutable, encode them as strings (crazy, but might work if you encapsulate all operations properly and don't tell your users that they are really strings). If your vectors are mutable, you have bigger problems because assignment, function arguments and returns all have reference semantics.

Comment: that's not possible in javascript and since typescript gets compiled to that you won't get it from it either.